# Insert Word Heading with Selection

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to insert a word heading at a specific position but it is always added at the end of the document. Where is my mistake?:

```
foreach (Publish p in tempstructure)
{
    if (p.element_type_id == 3)
    {
        Word.Paragraph par = selection.Paragraphs.Add();
        par.Range.Text = "test";
        par.Range.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2);
        par.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        selection.TypeParagraph();
    }
    else
    {
        if (File.Exists(@Properties.Settings.Default.documentsPath + p.filename + "_" + language + ".docx"))
        {
            selection.InsertFile(@Properties.Settings.Default.documentsPath + p.filename + "_" + language + ".docx");
            selection = word.Selection;
        }
        else
        {
            selection.TypeText("Missing file: " + p.filename + "_" + language + ".docx");
            selection.TypeParagraph();
        }
    }
    selection = word.Selection;
}
```

Best regards ...

Comment: Have you used the debugger..? also what is the heading supposed to say.. you realize that you are inside of a foreach loop.. so not sure what you expect.. the heading should be assigned outside of the loop

Comment: Hi, I'm adding different word documents to one single document. Between these documents there should be some headings. The debugger breaks at the right point, but the heading is added to the bottom of the document - I want it between so I am right in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is:

```
foreach (Publish p in tempstructure)
{
    if (p.element_type_id == 3)
    {                
       selection.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2);
       selection.TypeText(p.name);
       selection.TypeParagraph();
    }
    else
    {
        if (File.Exists(@Properties.Settings.Default.documentsPath + p.filename + "_" + language + ".docx"))
        {
            selection.InsertFile(@Properties.Settings.Default.documentsPath + p.filename + "_" + language + ".docx");
            selection = word.Selection;
        }
        else
        {
            selection.TypeText("Missing file: " + p.filename + "_" + language + ".docx");
            selection.TypeParagraph();
        }
    }
    selection = word.Selection;
}
```